# Javascript regex capture next word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am searching a regex to find next **word** after "dog" for example, and delete it

```
"123 dog rabbit cat".replace(myregex, "");
"123 dog cat"
```

Thanks

edit: but

```
"123 dog <b> ok</b> cat".replace(myregex, "");
```

should not do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to do that:

```
"123 dog rabbit cat".replace(/(dog) \w+/, '$1')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
"123 dog rabbit cat".replace(/dog (.*?)( |$)/, "dog ");
```

Comment: It could help to change the `.*` to `.*?` so that it is non-greedy. For example, "123 dog rabbit cat owls" would turn into "123 dog owls" with the `.*`, whereas it would be "123 dog cat owls" with the '.*?'.  You may also want to replace the trailing ' ' with `( |$)` in case the word after "dog" is at the end of the string, e.g. "123 dog cat".

Answer (score 1):

Expressions posted so far will fail on e.g. `123 dog <more spaces> rabbit cat`, so I think the `\s+\S+` or `\s+\w+` would be more accurate:

```
console.log("123 dog     rabbit! cat".replace(/(dog)\s+\S+/, '$1'))  // 123 dog cat
console.log("123 dog     rabbit! cat".replace(/(dog)\s+\w+/, '$1'))  // 123 dog! cat
```

I added `!` to your string to show the difference between `\S` and `\w`.

Comment: good I prefer WTK's answer though because I need to exclude other patterns: "123 dog <span> cat" should not remove anuthing after dog for example

Comment: @ca11111, I as wrote above, that pattern will fail if you happen to have two spaces after "dog"